# Xamarin.Forms release error bundles/armeabi-v7a/temp.c:1:39: fatal error: mono/metadata/mono-config.h: No such file or directory

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have error when release Xamarin.Forms with Visual Studio for Mac. Here is error

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2112,3): error XA5103: NDK C compiler resulted in an error. Exit code 0

> ```
> [cc stderr] obj/Release/bundles/armeabi-v7a/temp.c:1:39: fatal error: mono/metadata/mono-config.h: No such file or directory
> [cc stderr]  #include <mono/metadata/mono-config.h>
> [cc stderr]                                        ^
> [cc stderr] compilation terminated.
> [cc stderr]
> ```

And here is version of VS for mac

Visual Studio Professional 2017 for Mac
Version 7.0.1 (build 24)
Runtime:
    Mono 5.0.1.1 (2017-02/5077205) (64-bit) 
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Package version: 500010001
Xamarin.Android
Version: 7.3.1.1
SDK Tools Version: 26.0.2
SDK Platform Tools Version: 25.0.5
SDK Build Tools Version: 25.0.3

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 8.3.2 (12175)
Build 8E2002

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 10.10.0.36

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.12.4
Darwin 16.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just noticed the same error and found 2 issues. Seems like a bug that should be reported.

Do you have **Embed assemblies into native code** enabled by chance? You might even need to look for the `EmbedAssembliesIntoApk` in your Android project's `csproj` file to see if it is set to `true`. Make sure it is set to `false` or unchecked.

I also found that each time you deselect or select **Embed assemblies into native code** and then click the save button, it clears your selection of supported architectures to just one. So definitely check out your supported architectures after deselecting it **AND after clicking the save button**

Edit: This has been [reported to Xamarin](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56786)

Comment: Is there a work-around that will allow me to keep **Embed assemblies into native code** enabled?

Comment: @BrandonMinnick This needs to be reported to Xamarin for them to fix. I would assume that you could downgrade to a lower version of VS for Mac since I know it was working in previous versions (maybe 15.2 in VS for Mac or maybe the version just before that). You also might try building with Xamarin Studio instead. If you end up finding a way around it, please report back!

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Correction, it [has already been reported](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56786) and, hard for me to understand the thread but, it seems like it might be fixed in upcoming versions...?

Comment: Thanks @hvaughan3! I confirmed that the current stable release Xamarin Studio is still able to **Embed assemblies into native code**. I'll post another answer on this thread to help any other devs hitting the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

## Work-Around

For now, the work-around is to use the current stable release of Xamarin Studio to build the app, because it will successfully **Embed assemblies into native code** without errors!

As @hvaughan3 pointed out in the comments, this is a [known-issue](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56786) in Visual Studio for Mac, and is slated to be fixed in release 15.3.

Here's the details for the Stable release of Xamarin Studio for reference

## Xamarin Studio Details

=== Xamarin Studio Enterprise ===

Version 6.3 (build 864)
Installation UUID: 3ac98a61-67a7-411f-b124-19833ec9a519
Runtime:
    Mono 5.0.1.1 (2017-02/5077205) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Package version: 500010001

=== NuGet ===

Version: 3.5.0.0

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.5.4
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 8.3.2 (12175)
Build 8E2002

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 10.10.0.36 (Visual Studio Enterprise)
Hash: d2270eec
Branch: d15-2
Build date: 2017-05-22 16:30:53-0400

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 7.3.1.2 (Visual Studio Enterprise)
Android SDK: /Users/brandonm/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        4.1 (API level 16)
        6.0 (API level 23)
        7.0 (API level 24)
        7.1 (API level 25)

SDK Tools Version: 26.0.2
SDK Platform Tools Version: 25.0.5
SDK Build Tools Version: 25.0.3

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 3.4.0.36 (Visual Studio Enterprise)

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.2.2
Hash: b71b035
Branch: d15-1
Build date: Fri, 21 Apr 2017 17:57:12 GMT

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 603000864
Git revision: 6c2f6737278ccc3e81e12276d49c0d92f975f189
Build date: 2017-04-24 11:26:01-04
Xamarin addins: d8d46e577d8507c35260ce9d73df3c33415bb214
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-1

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.12.5
Darwin brandonm-mac.local 16.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0
    Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017
    root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

=== Enabled user installed addins ===

JSON Copy 1.1